# c# Parsing UTC datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse 11/23/2011 23:59:59 UTC +0800 as a c# datetime object but trying the standard datetime parse method or even the datetime exact parse I get invalid date.

Any ideas?

Comment: What time do you want? Do you live in a country that is UTC +08? Do you want your DateTime in UTC time (so 24 Nov 07:59) or what?

Comment: into the local time of the machine it is running on

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would suggest you parse to a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`, [as recommended in MSDN when using a time zone offset specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in the format string:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "11/23/2011 23:59:59 UTC +0800";
        string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC' zzz";

        DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact
            (text, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dto);
    }
}
```

You can then convert that to a `DateTime` value in UTC if you want, but there's no such thing as "a `DateTime` with an offset of 8 hours" - a `DateTime` is either regarded as universal, local or unspecified, with nowhere for a specific offset to be stored.

`DateTime` is a [curious type in various ways](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), and can cause problems for the unwary developer.

Answer (score 1):

Msdn for Format settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         //original date
        string _date = "Thu Jan 15 11:32:09 +0200 2015";
         // Describes the date format
        string _parsePattern = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"; 

         DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(_date, _parsePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

         //last settings
        Console.WriteLine(dto.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR")));
    }
}
```

for extension method:

```
public static DateTime getDateFromFormat(this string _date, string _parsePattern)
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(_date, _parsePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return Convert.ToDateTime(dto.ToLocalTime());
        }
```

For test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xdnjGy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ParseExact
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As written by James, you can try

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
         "11/23/2011 23:59:59 UTC +0800", 
         "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC' K", 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You'll get a date in the "local" time.