# Why are two hours added to my time

Tags: c#, .net

I'm struggling with time parsing. My input is a time string ending in "Z". I would expect that to be UTC. When I parse that string two hours are added to the result. I do not know why. Using a specific culture does not make any difference.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
string inTime = "2015-04-25T23:39:15Z";
DateTime outTime = DateTime.Parse(inTime, ci);
string outTime_string = outTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", ci);
// outTme and outTime_string are both 2015-04-26T01:39:15Z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `DateTime.Parse` converts to a "kind" of `Local`. (Print out `outTime.Kind` to verify that.) So it understands that the source is universal - but it's adjusting it to system local time. Note that *culture* has nothing to do with time zone - only format and calendar system.

You can prevent that by specifying a `DateTimeStyles` values:

```
DateTime outTime = DateTime.Parse(inTime, ci, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

At that point, `outTime.Kind` will be `Utc`, and the value will be 23:39pm as expected.

Quick plug: the whole `DateTime.Kind` bit is a mess. It's awful to have a type that represents three different kinds of value. You may want to look at my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for an alternate approach to date/time handling in .NET.

Answer (score 4):

It returns local time. [This will fix that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var x = DateTime.Parse(inTime, ci, 
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

[See this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913621/424129):

> I would suggest you parse to a DateTimeOffset instead of a DateTime, [as recommended in MSDN when using a time zone offset specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in the format string:

Time zones are a real pain to deal with.